# problema con sentencia preparada

Tags: php, mysql, poo, pdo, prepared-statements

Queria pedirles ayuda con un problema. Tengo un script para actualizar un registro con PDO, php, mysql y sentencias preparadas.
Para editar un registro, que ya esta cargado en un formulario, se entrega así cuando recibe por post los datos nuevos del formulario, en este caso un objeto usuario conformado por un id(autoincrement), nombres, apellidos, usuario y contraseña.

el id se recibe por

```
$id=$_GET['id']

$row = $this->consultarUsuario($id); //array asociativo con la info del usuario

if (($_POST['save'])) { //recibir formulario
                //valores recibidos por POST
                $nuevos = array(
                    "nombres" => $_POST["nombres"],
                    "apellidos" => $_POST["apellidos"],
                    "usuario" => $_POST["usuario"],
                    "contrasena" => $encriptar($_POST["contrasena"])
                );
                $tabla->setId($id);
                $tabla->setNombres($row['nombres']);
                $tabla->setApellidos($row['apellidos']);
                $tabla->setUsuario($row['usuario']);
                $tabla->setContrasena($encriptar($row['contrasena']));
                
                
                $tabla->actualizarUsuario($nuevos);
            }
```

y en la clase del usuario:

```
public function consultarUsuario($nik)
{
    $sql = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=:id"); //consultar la existencia de un usuario con el id recibido
    $sql->bindValue(':id', $nik, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute(); //ejecutar sentencia preparada con los parametros indicados
    $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sql = null; //liberar los datos almacenados en memoria de la consulta
    return $result;
}



  public function actualizarUsuario($nuevos)
{
  try {

   $update = $this->conexion->prepare("UPDATE `usuarios` SET `usuario`=:usuario, `nombres`=:nombres, `apellidos`=:apellidos, `contrasena`=:contrasena WHERE `id`=:id");
        //agregar variables a la sentencia preparada
        $update->bindValue(':nombres', $nuevos['nombres'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $update->bindValue(':apellidos', $nuevos['apellidos'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $update->bindValue(':usuario', $nuevos['usuario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $update->bindValue(':contrasena', $nuevos['contrasena'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $update->bindValue(':id', $this->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $update->execute(); //ejecutar sentencia preparada con los parametros indicados 
        //$x=$update->rowCount();
        if ($update->rowCount() > 0) { //AQUI ME DA rowCount = 0
            $n = "";

            //comparar valores nuevos con antiguos del usuario
            $n = cambios($this->getNombres(), $nuevos['nombres'], $n);
            $n = cambios($this->getApellidos(), $nuevos['apellidos'], $n);
            $n = cambios($this->getUsuario(), $nuevos['usuario'], $n);
            if (($this->getContrasena()) != ($nuevos['contrasena'])) {
                $n = $n . "Cambió su contraseña";
            }
      } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
```

Pero cuando le doy guardar en el formulario SIN CAMBIAR NINGÚN DATO, por alguna razón me arroja 0 con el rowCount() para verificar la operación en la linea if($update->rowCount() > 0), como si no se hubiera hecho el update.

Y solo funciona cuando cambio alguno de los valores que se envían como los nuevos, pero no debería pasar eso.

Alguno podría ayudarme por favor

Comment: @BetaM Pero si preparo la sentencia update, asigno los valores, y executo, no deberia aparecer una columna afectada?
o acaso el update no registra columnas afectadas si los valores son iguales?

Comment: si, aunque si es cierto del comentario que hice arriba, como podría hacerlo, si son iguales o diferentes?

Comment: Efectivamente busqué en la doc. de PHP y si los datos con los que intentas actualizar son idénticos a los ya existentes entonces te retornará 0, aqui puedes leer https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#104930 además incluye por parte del autor de la respuesta una posible solución

Comment: muchas gracias @BetaM, lo revisaré.

Comment: Pero la función __actualizarUsuario()__ llega a actualizar?

Comment: No logro entender cuál es tu problema exactamente ¿? Si intentas un UPDATE que no es tal, o sea, que establecería los mismos datos que ya existen sin ningún cambio, el valor de rowCount() será cero porque ese UPDATE no habrá modificado ninguna fila. Dicho eso, si tu BD es INNODB, considera usar restricciones de integridad referencial para mantener las tablas actualizadas. Aunque la pregunta no refleja todo el contexto, da la impresión de que esto no debería resolverse mediante código, sino aplicando integridad referencial si fuera posible.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ejecutar la misma consulta en PhpMyAdmin, primero con modificaciones (mostrará 1 fila afectada), luego sin modificaciones y no aparecerá el mensaje. Esto es una característica de MySQL que, por defecto, devuelve la cantidad de filas actualizadas (cero si los datos son iguales).

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html#codbc-dsn-option-flags):

> The client cannot handle when MySQL returns the true value of affected rows. If this flag is set, MySQL returns “found rows” instead. You must have MySQL 3.21.14 or newer for this to work.

El parámetro `FOUND_ROWS` se usa para que MySQL devuelva las filas encontradas en lugar de las afectadas. En PHP, puedes incluir la constante [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo.constants.mysql-attr-found-rows) al preparar una consulta con PDO  Ejemplo:

```
$update = $this->conexion->prepare(
    "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `usuario`=:usuario, `nombres`=:nombres,
    `apellidos`=:apellidos, `contrasena`=:contrasena WHERE `id`=:id",
    [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true]
);
```

Habría que probar si puede configurarse desde la conexión y si afecta o no el rendimiento general de tus scripts:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true]);
```

**Actualización:**

La discusión en comentarios ha estado muy interesante y sigo sin entender cuál sería el problema de obtener las filas encontradas en lugar de solo las actualizadas, quizá porque rara vez me veo en la necesidad de usar esa información, que tal vez suene extraño y, para algunos, también sea una *"mala práctica"*, pero se puede aclarar con los pasos que siempre sigo al hacer una actualización:

1. Obtener ID, validando tipo y valor
2. Leer la fila original para saber que existe
3. Validar que el usuario en sesión puede modificar la fila, ya sea por su rol (administrador / moderador) o porque el objeto le pertenece
4. Validar cada dato recibido (tipo, longitud, valor, etc.)
5. Si todos los pasos anteriores fueron correctos, ejecutar la consulta; de lo contrario, mostrar el mensaje de error correspondiente y finalizar
6. Si la consulta fue exitosa: ¡Los datos ya están actualizados! no creo necesario obtener la cantidad de filas afectadas

Ciertamente, como ya leí la fila, podría comparar si los datos nuevos son iguales a los que ya están guardados para no ejecutar la consulta, pero no lo hago y tal vez sería un área de oportunidad para no consumir recursos innecesariamente. Seguramente lo analizaré con calma en un futuro cercano... ¿o no?

Para actualizar múltiples filas, ya es otro cantar, ahí sí creo más conveniente obtener solo las filas afectadas en lugar de todas las que coinciden con el filtro. Dependiendo de las necesidades del proyecto y preferencias del usuario, es donde hay que analizar la viabilidad de esta característica y en qué contextos.

Comment: He votado en contra porque no veo en qué ayuda meterse a cambiar el estado habitual de las cosas para querer ¿resolver? un problema cuya solución estaría a otro nivel. Un UPDATE que no actualiza nada es normal que devuelva cero, ¿por qué hay que inventar para cambiar ese comportamiento? Además esto debería resolverse aplicando restricciones de integridad referencial si fuera posible, ni siquiera por código PHP.

Comment: +1 por mi parte. Ahora @A.Cedano, está claro que no tiene lógica de Actualizar datos de auto rellenado, si estos no han sido modificado, para ellos se podría comprobar mediante `PHP` si los datos enviado por `POST` son igual a los guardados en la BD, si es así no se actualiza y si son diferente se hace el `UPDATE`, pero desde mi punto de vista si contesta a la pregunta: `Pero cuando le doy guardar en el formulario SIN CAMBIAR NINGÚN DATO, por alguna razón me arroja 0 con el rowCount() para verificar la operación en la línea if($update->rowCount() > 0), como si no se hubiera hecho el update.`

Comment: @Diablo la respuesta a la pregunta ¡es la misma pregunta!, si se aplica el sentido común. **El rowCount arroja 0 porque no había nada que actualizar. El UPDATE no se hizo porque no era tal.** No hay que darle más vueltas. Sugerir que se cambie la configuración para que la conexión circule por el carril contrario me parece contraproducente.

Comment: @A.Cedano, es la primera vez que no me alegro de ver tus comentarios en mis publicaciones y nada tiene que ver si votas en contra o a favor; me extraña que tu único argumento sea usar una variable de configuración que por algo está ahí, MySQL la tiene disponible para cualquier controlador y PHP no es la excepción. Lo menos que esperaría es un razonamiento de porqué puede ser contraproducente e, incluso, mencioné esa posibilidad al final de la respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano, respecto a tu pregunta _"¿por qué hay que inventar para cambiar ese comportamiento?"_, la respuesta es tan sencilla como que el usuario así lo requiere, no desea verificar si los datos cambiaron antes de ejecutar la consulta; si es buena práctica o no, es discutible (no encontré referencias ni a favor ni en contra) y, lo más importante, es su decisión habilitar o no una característica que tiene a su alcance y su responsabilidad analizar los beneficios o perjuicios, en caso de haberlos.

Comment: Triby, ese no es mi único argumento, ni el principal. Lee mis otros comentarios en tu respuesta y en la misma pregunta. Creo que cuando alguien se equivoca es deber nuestro decírselo. En este caso OP se equivoca del todo y confunde lo que es una actualización o cree que el SGBD debería comportarse de una determinada manera cuando una actualización no ocurre. Además, como ya dije en otros comentarios, creo que esto no debería resolverse a nivel de PHP, sino en la BD.

Comment: ¿@A.Cedano, entonces es un error que exista esa posibilidad en MySQL? Porque también lo puedes configurar en ODBC.

Comment: No digo que sea un error que exista, sino que a mi entender, usar esa opción para resolver el problema planteado aquí, es erróneo. Los motivos ya los he expuesto: cuando una actualización no ocurre rowCount devuelve cero , en un UPDATE el interés real sería conocer las filas que se actualizaron, si modificas este parámetro podrías terminar trabajando con información fuera de la realidad. Además, este tipo de problemas deberían resolverse definiendo restricciones en las tablas, no por código PHP.

Comment: @A.Cedano, ese _"a mi entender"_ deja muy claro que se trata de una cuestión de preferencias y, como dije antes, si se trata o no de una mala práctica, tu argumento debería estar soportado con referencias y no con opinión personal. ¿En qué afecta esa configuración? en que cada que realices una actualización va a devolver las filas encontradas, independientemente de si se hicieron cambios o no. ¿Hay diferencia de rendimiento? Eso habría que probarlo. ¿Hay riesgos de seguridad o integridad de tablas? Sinceramente, lo dudo mucho. ¿Debería validar en PHP? Definitivamente SÍ.